# How can I align iconbutton and text?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I created 4 Icon buttons in the row field. I placed these IconButtons evenly on the screen with `mainAxisAlignment`. Then I created 4 texts. I connected the iconbuttons and texts to each other with the column class. However, I could not succeed in ordering the Textbuttons and Texts one under the other.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart'; 

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
          children: [
            Column(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.medical_services,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Text("MEDİCAL"),
            Column(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.medical_services,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Text("MEDİCAL"),
            Column(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.medical_services,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Text("MEDİCAL"),
            Column(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(
                    Icons.medical_services,
                    color: Colors.black,
                    size: 40,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            ),
            Text("MEDİCAL"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

What can i do to fix the misaligned image in the picture?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `Text` Widget inside the `Column` widget instead of `Row`

[image]

```
  Column(
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.medical_services,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 40,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
SizedBox(height: 5,),
                    Text("MEDİCAL"),
                  ],
                ),
```

**Tip:** Instead of duplicating this widget(reducing the code size) you convert the widget into single widget or component  like this

```
    class MainButton extends StatelessWidget {
  MainButton(
      {Key? key,
      required this.medical_services,
      required this.color,
      required this.size2,
      required this.text,
      required this.onPressed2})
      : super(key: key);
  var medical_services = Icons.medical_services;
  var color = Colors.black;
  double size2 = 40;
  var text = "MEDİCAL";
  VoidCallback? onPressed2 = () {};

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            medical_services,
            color: color,
            size: size2,
          ),
          onPressed: onPressed2,
        ),
        SizedBox(height: 5,),
        Text(text),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

call like this

```
   MainButton(
              medical_services: Icons.medical_services,
              color: Colors.black,
              size2: 40,
              text: "Medical Service",
              onPressed2: () {},
            )
```

[You can check in dartpad](http://dartpad.dev/?id=c0e497dd9ded7c8045cb41724aea7409)

Answer (score 2):

Move the **Text** widgets inside the **Column** widget that contains the **IconButton**, I see them outside, at the same level of the **Column**; they should be placed inside the **Column**, as follows:

```dart
Column(
   children: [
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(
          Icons.medical_services,
          color: Colors.black,
          size: 20, // also decreased the size of the icon a bit
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
     ),
     Text("MEDİCAL"), // here, inside the column
   ],
),
```

then they would look like this:

[image]

Is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I wanted to achieve. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

put text inside column
try this way

```
 Column(
                   
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(
                        Icons.medical_services,
                        color: Colors.black,
                        size: 40,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                    
                    Spacer(),
                     Text("MEDİCAL"),
                  ],
                ),
```